# Hive parse json elements from a long concat json string

Tags: json, hive, hiveql

I have a server log, it continuously records json values without any delimiter, such as:

`{"a":1}{"b",2}{"a":2}{"c":{\"qwe\":\"asd\"},"d":"ert"}{"e":12}....`

I want to extract each element and put them into rows like:

```
{"a":1}
{"b",2}
{"a":2}
{"c":{\"qwe\":\"asd\"},"d":"ert"}
{"e":12}..
```

The log lacks delimiter and comprises nested json, so I cannot use 
`split` function...How to achieve this...

Comment: What datatype is this field stored as? Is this a string or struct?

Comment: Hi~ @EdwardMendez This is a string field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to `split` on `}{` character and get the elements using `posexplode`. Positions are only needed to concatenate properly for the first and last elements.

```
select case when pos = 0 then concat(split_str,'}') 
            when pos = max(pos) over(partition by str) then concat('{',split_str) 
       else concat('{',split_str,'}') end as res
from tbl 
lateral view posexplode(split(str,'\\}\\{')) t as pos,split_str
```

Note the result will be a `string`.